# Installing PHP extensions in Plesk Obsidian - idiots guide required

Tags: php, apache, plesk

I'm trying to upload files *from my server to an another server* via SFTP.
I'm running Plesk Obsidian 18.0.31 Update #3 - ‪CentOS 6.10 (Final)‬

From what I understand I need to install some extensions to PHP to allow this ?

Mainly to run these commands:

- ssh2_connect()
- ssh2_auth_password()
- ssh2_sftp()

Sorry for being a little vague but my knowledge of servers is limited.

Any help is appreciated whether to solve my immediate problem or to offer a different solution !

Elaboration:
I have a PHP script that produces a JSON file which, on creation needs to be transferred via SFTP to another host. The external host isn't controlled by me but I do have the connection details.

Comment: You may want to elaborate on exactly what you are doing.   sftp works over ssh, and has nothing to do with PHP - ie PHP definitely does not need to be installed on the server to copy files using SFTP (or SCP).    First thing to do is get SSH access into the first server.  Then set it up so you can SSH from the first server to the second.   Once you have this done you can use sftp (or SCP which may be easier) to copy from the first to the second server.

Comment: Elaborated . . .

Comment: Ouch. This is not trivial even if you are a seasoned admin - and relying on s version of CentOS/Redhat that's been undupported for 2.5 years wont help.  Per https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360058567934-How-do-I-install-ssh2-for-php- it looks like you will need to do this in a terminal.  Look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/ssh2.installation.php

Comment: If this is a script, have you considered writing a bash script as a wrapper (which calls tje php script and then does the upload?  That might be easier.

Comment: Maybe you could use a shell call from php to do the upload instead?   Ive also found https://phpseclib.com/ which may provide an alternative api in php.

Comment: If you need those extensions installed and you don't have root access to terminal or easyapache or don't know how, ask your hosting service to do it.